# pip roto e imposible de crear un entorno

Tags: python

No puedo instalar un paquete o crear un entorno virtual :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/recordwrite$ python -m pip install pyaudio --user
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
  Complete output from command /home/mike/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-090irkg_/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-pj974zkh --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/mike/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /home/mike/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-090irkg_/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-k4v5z2mv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/mike/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/mike/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-090irkg_/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-k4v5z2mv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-090irkg_/pyaudio/
```

Y cuando intento crear un environment me dice que devuelto un estado de salida no cero, que, a mi parecer significa que hay errores :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/recordwrite$ python3 -m venv envError: Command '['/home/mike/Documents/programming/recordwrite/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Aún me las arreglé creando un entorno sin `pip` y volviéndolo a instalar después pero es realmente una molestia.

Aqui esta mi version de Python :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful/extractText$ python -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

Cuando intento crear el entorno virtual que tengo, me contesta el terminal :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful/extractText$ python -m virtualenv env
Using base prefix '/home/mike/anaconda3'
New python executable in /home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin/python
/home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: The executable /home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText' (should be '/home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Y cuendo intento activarlo no hay el `activate` :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin$ ls
python  python3  python3.6
```

Comment: al parecer no tienes las librerias para compilar en tu sistema operativo si estas usando sistema operativos basados en debian intenta ejecutar el comando `sudo apt-get install build-essential` y `sudo apt-get install python3-dev ` para python3 esa libreria tiene C y otras cosas para compilar

Comment: @JackNavaRow Utiliso ubuntu16.04. tus órdenes me dan `0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 65 not to upgrade`

Comment: cambia el dueño de la carpeta al usuario mike e intenta, sospecho que la carpeta no tiene permisos

Comment: @JackNavaRow Correcto. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: `sudo chown -R mike:mike recordwrite`

Comment: @JackNavaRow Hmm, me contesta `chown: cannot access 'recordwrite': No such file or directory`

Comment: debes hacwerlo donde esta la carpeta `sudo chown -R mike:mike 
 ~/Documents/programming/recordwrite`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84107/discussion-between-thepassenger-and-jacknavarow).